# MVC Razor Select option Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My problem is i can not get my select options values from my controller.
My model islike this.

```
    public class MergeAccount
    {

    public virtual Identity.ApplicationUser SourceUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Identity.ApplicationUser TargetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual string Pincode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Securitycode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime MergeDate { get; set; }
    }
```

and my view

```
  <select class="select2-single form-control" id="TargetUser" name="TargetUser">
                                <option value="">Target Account</option>
                                @foreach (var item in UserList)
                                {

                                     <option value="@item.Id">@item.UserName</option>
                                }
```

controller side

```
    public ActionResult DoMergeAccount(MergeAccount merge)
    {
         var targetusrId = merge.TargetUser ;  <---- 
    }
```

merge.TargetUser always is null , any idea how i can get selectoption values ?

Comment: inspect dropdown using firebug or something and see what is in value="@item.Id"

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (which `ApplicationUser` is). I recommend you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics, in particular how to generate views which are strongly bound to your model using the `HtmlHelper` methods (`@Html.DropDownListFor()`)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway i can get values with

> string targetuser = Request["TargetUser"];

but it shouldnt fill my model automaticly if models property id/names  same with dropdowns ?